# Polymer reset parameters format not working

Tags: forms, polymer, field, reset

I am new to Polymer 2.0. I need to update a field called Print Name to set the values I put in First Name + Last Name. Currently I get a version of it that is not working as I get bad request. **'System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.'**

```
_updateField(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.set('_contract.signeeContact.printName', [this._contract.signeeContact.firstName, this._contract.signeeContact.lastName]);
                // printName: ["firstName", "LastName"] // this is not correct it should be
                // printName: ["firstName LastName"] // correct request should look like this
            }
```

the format is not correct. Can someone give me a hand with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it expects an array with one string inside, you're passing it an array with two strings inside. `[this._contract.signeeContact.firstName + " " + this._contract.signeeContact.lastName]`. Although it's likely that it doesn't want an array at all so if that doesn't work you might want to try just `this._contract.signeeContact.firstName + " " + this._contract.signeeContact.lastName` without the brackets.

Comment: @GuyIncognito thank you. Worked! I must have tried at least 10 different combinations of having + or && between the two strings nothing worked! :)