# removing unwanted quotes from a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, escaping, quotation-marks

I have a string that outputs like this:

```
"firstName" "lastName"
```

I need to the output to be like

```
"firtName lastName"
```

or else I get bad string request. I have tried different regex combinations that could achieve that however so far I can remove the quotes at the beginning and end of the string and the ones in the middle.

```
var string = '"firstName" ,"lastName"';
var stringWithoutCommas = string.replace(/,/g, '');
var stringWithoutExtQuotes = stringWithoutCommas.replace(/^"(.+(?="$))"$/, '$1');
console.log(stringWithoutExtQuotes); //firstName" "lastName
```

thanks you.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It would probably be much better to fix the bad string request properly instead of removing the quotes manually.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I have another stackoverflow question here pertaining to this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254872/polymer-reset-parameters-format-not-working unfortunately not a lot of folks know this framework.

Comment: yyeah ok I'll add a comment to the other question. Doesn't look like this is an issue about quotes at all.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = '"firstName" ,"lastName"';

console.log(
  string.replace(/"(\w*)\W*(\w*)"/, function(_, match1, match2){
    return `"${match1} ${match2}"`;
  })
);
```

You could grab the two strings and rebuild the string you want.

Answer (score 1):

One approach

```js
const input = '"firstName" "lastName"'

console.log('"'+input.replace(/"(.+?)"/g,'$1')+'"')
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract all between double quotes and join the results:

```js
const string = '"firstName" ,"lastName"';
console.log(Array.from(string.matchAll(/"([^"]+)"/g), x=>x[1]).join(" "));
```

**Regex**: `"([^"]+)"`

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]+                    any character except: '"' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/wCRugk/1).

Answer (score -1):

This should be answer to your question.

```
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var result = fruits.join(",");
}
```

Comment: Not my DV, but this answer has nothing to do with the question.